# SQL: Setting column value based on rows appearing after it

Tags: sql, db2

I am creating a kind of dynamic web form where users can drag and drop fields to create their own forms. The elements are grouped by a header which is stored in the table as type `H`. In the table below, there are two groups, 1-4 and 5-6.

There is a requirement that the field appears in the final form if its `RLS_FLAG` is Y which the user can set. However, the value of `RLS_FLAG` for elements of type `H` is automatic based on whether any fields in the same group have been set to `Y`.

```
+------+----------+----------+
| TYPE | SEQUENCE | RLS_FLAG |
+------+----------+----------+
| H    | 1        | Y        |
+------+----------+----------+
| D    | 2        | N        |
+------+----------+----------+
| P    | 3        | Y        |
+------+----------+----------+
| D    | 4        | N        |
+------+----------+----------+
| H    | 5        | Y        |
+------+----------+----------+
| D    | 6        | Y        |
+------+----------+----------+
```

There will be only one element of type `P`, and given the sequence number of this element, I need to find all the rows in the same group, check if any of them have `RLS_FLAG` set to `Y` and set the `RLS_FLAG` of group header.

I came up with the below query, but I am sure it is the worst possible one, and I need a few suggestions on optimizing the query.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET RLS_FLAG = 'Y' WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE RLS_FLAG = 'Y' 
    AND SEQUENCE > ( SELECT COALESCE ( MAX( SEQUENCE ), 0 ) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TYPE = 'H' AND SEQUENCE < ( SELECT SEQUENCE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TYPE = 'P'))
    AND SEQUENCE < ( SELECT COALESCE ( MIN( SEQUENCE ), 999 ) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TYPE = 'H' AND SEQUENCE > ( SELECT SEQUENCE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TYPE = 'P'))
)
```

In the statement above, I am trying to find the sequence of `H` element above `P` and sequence of `H` element below `P`. Then find all rows between two values and check if any of them have `RLS_FLAG` set to `Y`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of expressing the logic:

```
update t
    set rls_flag = 'Y'
    where type = 'H' and
          exists (select 1
                  from (select t2.*,
                               lead(case when type = 'H' then sequence end) over (order by sequence) as next_h_sequence
                        from t t2
                       ) t2
                  where t2.rls_flag = 'Y' and
                        t2.sequence >= t.sequence and t2.sequence < next_h_sequence
                 );
```